# c | compare string format

Tags: c, ansi-c

I want to find out if there is any simple option to a string is equal to a format string.
for example I want this format `.mat[something][something]` to be equal to using `strcmp` to `.mat[r1][r2]` or `.mat[4][5]`

Is there any option to use regular expressions of a sort? or something like `strcmp(.mat[%s][%s], .mat[r3][r5])`?

BTW I'm using ansi-c
Thanks

Comment: ansi-c doesn't have support for regular expressions. You can use POSIX regexps if you are on Posix system.

Comment: You want regex, not string comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the closest thing to regular expression, `scanf` scan sets, this would work, but it is remarkably ugly:

```
char row[20], col[20], bracket[2], ignored;
if (sscanf(input, ".mat[%19[^]]][%19[^]]%1[]]%c", row, col, bracket, &ignored) == 3) {
    // row and col contain the corresponding specifications...    
    // bracket contains "]"
    // %c failed to convert because if the end of string
    ....
}
```

Here is the broken down conversion specification for `".mat[r1][r2]"`:

```
".mat["    // matches .mat[
"%19[^]]"  // matches r1   count=1
"]["       // matches ][
"%19[^]]"  // matches r2   count=2
"%1[]]"    // matches ]    count=3
"%c"       // should not match anything because of the end of string
```

Comment: Maybe `".mat[%19[^]][%19[^]]%1[]]%c"`   ( 1 less `]`)

Comment: @chux: Amazingly unreadable isn't it? The third `]` is needed to match the `]` in the string. It is not present for the second part because `%1[]]` matches the second `]` in the string.

Comment: Agree  3 `]]]`  For somewhat improved readability  `#define INDEX "%19[^]]" ... ".mat[" INDEX "][" INDEX "%1[]]%c"`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573352/2410359) fine answer: This allows for various suffixes and no `bracket[2]`

Use `"%n"` which saves the scan offset.  It will be non-zero if scanning succeeded up to that point

```
// .mat[something][something]
#define PREFIX ".mat"
#define IDX "[%19[^]]]"
#define SUFFIX ""

char r1[20], r2[20];
int n = 0;
sscanf(input, PREFIX INDEX INDEX SUFFIX "%n", r1, r2, &n);

// Reached the end and there was no more
if (n > 0 && input[n] == '\0') Success();
else Failure();
```